# Threadsafe treeview node image index change in C#

Tags: c#, treeview, thread-safety

How can i change image index of a tree view node in a threadsafe manner? There is no Invoke() method for TreeNode class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `Invoke` on the form instead of the component itself.

Component code executes on the thread of the form, so an invoke on a component simply delegates the operation to the form's thread. You'll get exactly the same result by using `form.Invoke` as you would `form.component.Invoke`.